# OpenFire restart runs setup process again and again

Tags: linux, rhel7, openfire

I am new to OpenFire and I am using the version 3.9.3

The problem is that every time I restart OpenFire, I must go through the same setup process. In my case, I would like not to go through it every time I reboot the service.

This is how openfire.xml looks for me:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <autosetup>
        <run>true</run>
        <locale>en</locale>
        <xmpp>
            <domain>localhost</domain>
            <fqdn>localhost</fqdn>
            <auth>
                <anonymous>true</anonymous>
            </auth>
            <socket>
                <ssl>
                    <active>false</active>
                </ssl>
            </socket>
        </xmpp>
        <encryption>
            <algorithm>Blowfish</algorithm>
        </encryption>
        <database>
            <mode>standard</mode>
            <defaultProvider>
                <driver>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driver>
                <serverURL>jdbc:mysql://mysql:5432/openfire</serverURL>
                <username>openfire</username>
                <password>openfire</password>
                <minConnections>5<minConnections>
                <maxConnections>25<maxConnections>
                <connectionTimeout>1.0<connectionTimeout>
            </defaultProvider>
        </database>
        <admin>
            <email>admin@example.com</email>
        <password>admin</password>
        </admin>
        <authprovider>
            <mode>default</mode>
        </authprovider>
        <users>
            <user1> <!-- Use incremental numbers for more users, eg: user2, user3 -->
                <username>jose</username> <!-- Required -->
                <password>jose</password> <!-- Required -->
                <name>jose</name>
                <email>jose@example.com</email>
                <roster>
                    <item1> <!-- Use incremental numbers for more items, eg: item2, item3 -->
                        <jid>jose@example.com</jid>
                        <nickname>John</nickname>
                    </item1>
                </roster>
            </user1>
        </users>
    </autosetup>
```

Is there anything wrong with my openfire.xml file?

Any help is welcome! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What made it work for me was the following:

Enter into mysql database (if using mysql), connect to openfire database, and then perform the following SQL query:
`INSERT INTO ofProperty (NAME,PROPVALUE) VALUES ('setup','true');`

After that, the problem was solved.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the `<run>` value from `<run>true</run>` to `<run>false</run>` and restart your server

Comment: Hi, sorry I did not update but what made it work for me was the following SQL query:`INSERT INTO ofProperty (NAME,PROPVALUE) VALUES ('setup','true');`